# Retrieve data from Mysql database PHP MVC

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my code in model.php

```
public function getQuestion($id){

$query = mysql_query("select * from bm_question where que_catid = '".$id."'");
return $query;
}

public function getAnswerforQuestion($qid){

$query1 = mysql_query("select * from bm_answer where ans_quid = '".$qid."'"); 
return $query1;

}
```

And also below is my controller.php

```
public function index() {

$this->load->model('quizmodel');
$qArr = $this->bm_question->getQustions(que_id);

foreach ($qArr as $value) {    

//Output Question
echo $value ->que_question;

    $this->load->model('quizmodel');
$ansArr=$this->answer->getAnswerforQuestion($value ->que_id);
foreach ($ansArr as $value2) {    
    //output answer
    echo $value2 ->answer;
}
}
```

Finally I bellow error for this code.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested but it should work.Try like below:
Your Model:

```
public function getQuestion($id){
   $query = $this->db->query("select * from bm_question where que_catid='$id'");
   return $query->result();
}
```

Load your model in your controller like below:

```
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('quizmodel');
}
```

Your controller :

```
public function index(){
$qArr = $this->bm_question->getQuestions($que_id);
foreach($qArr as $value){
    // your code    
   }
}
```

Comment: thanx @Nagendra. But result is same. Error is appear for $qArr = $this->bm_question->getQustions(que_id) line

Comment: @LakshithaGihan change `bm_question` to `Bm_question` and it  should be your model name.Change  `getQuestions(que_id)` to `getQuestions($que_id)`.You missed `$` here.

Comment: Thanx @Nagendra. This time it display 'Call to undefined method quizmodel::getQustion()' also for this line.